# Find distinct x and corresponding y

Tags: splunk

I have a set of records with multiple duplicate values across two fields X, and Y. I would like to write a splunk query to find distinct X, and its corresponding Y value. I am completely lost, and have no clue on how to come up with this query. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is probably as simple as

```
| dedup X Y | table X Y
```

This will find all distinct combinations of X and Y and remove all duplicates, then display the result in a table.

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
stats values(x) by y
```

or

```
stats values(y) by x
```

Depending on how you want to view the data. Per Splunk documentation, "In a distributed environment, stats is likely to be faster, because the indexers can "prestats" before sending their results to the search head"

Answer (score 0):

give these two links a bash!

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0/SearchReference/Dedup

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0/SearchReference/CommonStatsFunctions